# Make intersection of two methods in typescript

Tags: typescript, recoiljs

I have intersection type GetSet and instances of Get and Set. How can I compose the GetSet instance? `get & set` gives two errors:

- TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type
- TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetSet'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Get'

```js
type Get = (<T>(a: RecoilValue<T>) => T)
type Set = (<T>(s: RecoilState<T>, u: (((currVal: T) => T) | T)) => void)
export type GetSet = Get & Set;

// some external functions
let get: Get; 
let set: Set;

function callback(getSet: GetSet) {
}

function perform() {
    callback(get & set); // <--- error here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calback(get & set)` is plain wrong it will change to `0` in JavaScript (try `(function () {}) & (function() {})` in chrome console), there is no `&` operator that will combine functions in JavaScript. `type GetSet = Get & Set` is a type definition in TypeScript which only means that the definition is a combination of both. However, there is no such thing in JavaScript.

If you want to pass two functions in JavaScript, you have to either use Tuple/Array or Object Literal.

```
   callback([get, set]);
   // or
   callback({ get, set });
```

However, In this case, the callback definition should change as follow,

```
type Get = (<T>(a: RecoilValue<T>) => T)
type Set = (<T>(s: RecoilState<T>, u: (((currVal: T) => T) | T)) => void)
export type GetSet = { get: Get, set: Set };

// some external functions
let get: Get; 
let set: Set;

function callback({ get, set }: GetSet) {
}

function perform() {
    callback({ get , set }); // <--- this is correct way
}
```

You can combine `get` `set` as a single function as shown below...

```
function getOrSet(... a: any[]) {
    if (a.length === 1) {
        return get(a[0]);        
    }
    return set(a[0], a[1]);
}
```

If you look at how jQuery was organized, you can call same method without parameter to get value and if you pass a parameter, it will set the value.

This might require rewriting many definitions.

Comment: Separate `get` and `set` is what I have currently in dozens of callback methods.

Comment: When I asked ChatGPT if there is a way to reduce boilerplate it suggested me the construction of `GetSet`. It compiles well everywhere except the place of actual call from separate `get` and `set`. I wondered if there is some new magic with typescript that could combine both methods, but looks like ChatGPT as always suggests imaginary construction that fits well into the question but don't exist in real framework.

Comment: @Ben you can combine `get` and `set` as shown in edited answer.